# Merge objects in collection where fields are same

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to merge and update objects where 4 fields (name, panel, section, subsection) are the same.

*i.e.*

Data merged 1: *name = 'Field Handbook v1.1' and section = 'customer' and subsection = 'manuals' and panel = 'Revolution Series (R3 Series)'*

Data merged 2: *name = 'Field Handbook v1.1' and section = 'customer' and subsection = 'manuals' and panel = 'Eco-Safe Digester (E3 Series)'*

**Initial Objects**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d35e1fd02819f105326c84e"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "files" : [
        {
            "ext" : "pdf",
            "file" : "Revolution Series Digester Field Handbook R3 Series v1.1 150 DPI.pdf"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Field Handbook v1.1",
    "section" : "customer",
    "subsection" : "manuals",
    "tags" : [
        "customer",
        "manuals"
    ],
    "panel" : "Revolution Series (R3 Series)"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d35e1fd02819f105326c851"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "files" : [
        {
            "ext" : "link",
            "file" : "http://docs.biohitech.com/r3/handbook"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Field Handbook v1.1",
    "section" : "customer",
    "subsection" : "manuals",
    "tags" : [
        "customer",
        "manuals"
    ],
    "panel" : "Revolution Series (R3 Series)"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d35e1fd02819f105326c856"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "files" : [
        {
            "ext" : "pdf",
            "file" : "Eco-Safe Digester Field Handbook E3 Series v1.1 150 DPI.pdf"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Field Handbook v1.1",
    "section" : "customer",
    "subsection" : "manuals",
    "tags" : [
        "customer",
        "manuals"
    ],
    "panel" : "Eco-Safe Digester (E3 Series)"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d35e1fd02819f105326c857"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "files" : [
        {
            "ext" : "link",
            "file" : "http://docs.biohitech.com/e3/handbook/"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Field Handbook v1.1",
    "section" : "customer",
    "subsection" : "manuals",
    "tags" : [
        "customer",
        "manuals"
    ],
    "panel" : "Eco-Safe Digester (E3 Series)"
}
```

**Intended Results**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d35e1fd02819f105326c84e"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "files" : [
        {
            "ext" : "pdf",
            "file" : "Revolution Series Digester Field Handbook R3 Series v1.1 150 DPI.pdf"
        },
        {
            "ext" : "link",
            "file" : "http://docs.biohitech.com/r3/handbook"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Field Handbook v1.1",
    "section" : "customer",
    "subsection" : "manuals",
    "tags" : [
        "customer",
        "manuals"
    ],
    "panel" : "Revolution Series (R3 Series)"
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d35e1fd02819f105326c856"),
    "deleted" : false,
    "files" : [
        {
            "ext" : "pdf",
            "file" : "Eco-Safe Digester Field Handbook E3 Series v1.1 150 DPI.pdf"
        },
        {
            "ext" : "link",
            "file" : "http://docs.biohitech.com/e3/handbook/"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Field Handbook v1.1",
    "section" : "customer",
    "subsection" : "manuals",
    "tags" : [
        "customer",
        "manuals"
    ],
    "panel" : "Eco-Safe Digester (E3 Series)"
}
```

Comment: So you wanted to update DB back ? what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: @whoami I have a collection that has nearly identical documents, with the only difference being the *files* array. I  want to merge the documents into one document with both *files* array concatenated, and remove the documents that where used to create the new document.

Comment: @whoami db version v4.0.11

Comment: Okay with `4.011` we can aggregate on your collection & write aggregation result to other collection(collection_new)  & drop existing then buy renaming `collection_new` to old/actual name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$files",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "name": "$name",
                "section": "$section",
                "subsection": "$subsection",
                "panel": "$panel"
            },
            data: {
                $first: "$$ROOT"
            },
            files: {
                $push: "$files"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "data.files": "$files"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$data"
        }
    },
    /** writes to new collection named 'collection_new' will override collection if that name already exists */
    { $out: "collection_new" }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZORGLtF0hLx)

Once you feel the data is good in `collection_new` then you might need to drop existing collection & rename this to old/actual name, Also check for indexes. In case if you can upgrade to `>4.2` then you can use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html) which will append docs to existing collection, which is much cleaner in usage.